# How can I manipulate tabular data with python?

Tags: python

I have column-based data in a CSV file and I would like to manipulate it in several ways. People have pointed me to R because it gives you easy access to both rows and columns, but I am already familiar with python and rather use it.

For example, I want to be able to delete all the rows that have a certain value in one of the columns. Or I want to change all the values of one column (i.e., trim the string). I also want to be able to aggregate rows based on common values (like a SQL GROUP BY).

Is there a way to do this in python without having to write a loop to iterate over all of the rows each time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library.  It provides a DataFrame type similar to R's dataframe that lets you do the kind of thing you're talking about.

Comment: ah ha! I knew there had to be something like that, but I just couldn't find it.